# Setting Up Windows System Variables with Python

Tags: operating-system, gdal, sys

I am looking to set up two separate system variables through python, so that both gdal_calc and gdal_translate will work properly on my computer. However, it the pathway's that I have appended and the variables that I have added don't seem to be working properly. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import sys
import os


# make dictionary of environmental variables to set up for gdal_calc and gdal_translate

gdal_env = os.environ.copy()

# modify and add variables for environment so that GDAL runs properly

gdal_env["GDAL_DATA"] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal-data"
gdal_env["GDAL_DRIVER_PATH"] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdalplugins"
gdal_env["PATH"] = gdal_env["PATH"] + ";C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\bin"

# Set constants
# The pathway to the images files are nested within the '--outfile=' command

inHVFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Float32\\newHV32.img')
outPlacement = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Zeros\\newHVZeros_1.img')
outVFile = '--outfile=' + outPlacement
#calc_cmd_HV = ['gdal_calc.py', '-A', inHVFile, outVFile, '--calc=A+1']

inVHFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Float32\\newVH32.img')
outPlacement_1 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Zeros\\newVHZeros_1.img')
outVFile_1 = '--outfile=' + outPlacement_1
#calc_cmd_VH = ['gdal_calc.py', '-A', inVHFile, outVFile_1, '--calc=A+1']


subprocess.call([sys.executable,'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py', inHVFile, outVFile, '--calc=A+1'], env=gdal_env)
subprocess.call([sys.executable,'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py', inVHFile, outVFile_1, '--calc=A+1'], env=gdal_env)
#subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inHVFile, outVFile, '--calc=A+1'])

#subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inVHFile, outVFile_1, '--calc=A+1'])
```

Comment: How are they not working properly? Are you trying to use `subprocess.call` to call gdal_calc and gdal_translate?

Comment: Initially I ran my script within a command prompt and it suggested that the pathway to GDAL didn't exist and that it couldn't locate the dll files. Then, subsequently, everything ran properly. 

Any idea why it wouldn't be able to find the dll files, or why it worked regardless of the script being able to locate them? 

And I am using subprocess.call to run both gdal_calc and gdal_translate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environmental variables hold information about where files and programs can be found. When using Python to call commandline programs via `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen`, you can specify a set of environmental variables at the time the subprocess is spawned. This is done by passing a dictionary to the `env` kwarg of `call` or `Popen`. If `env` is not specified, the default environmental variables will be used.

Modifications to the environmental variables stored in `os.environ` will not persist after the Python session has ended.

To call GDAL programs via `subprocess.call`, do the following:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

# make dictionary of environmental variables
gdal_env = os.environ.copy()

# modify and add variables
gdal_env["GDAL_DATA"] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\gdal-data"
gdal_env["GDAL_DRIVER_PATH"] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdalplugins"
gdal_env["PATH"] = gdal_env["PATH"] + ";C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\bin"


# ... do preparation ...
a = "a.tif"
b = "b.tif"
output = "output.tif"

calc_cmd = [sys.executable, 'gdal_calc.py', '-A', a, '-B', b, '--outfile='+output, '--calc=A+B']

# spawn a new subprocess
subprocess.call(calc_cmd, env=gdal_env)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've made changes to my script, however I am receiving an error 
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Do you know what this means?

Comment: @KosherMoses I don't know what that error means, I don't really work on Windows. It might be that you need to run the `gdal_calc.py` script from `python`, so run `subprocess.call` like you have in your other questions:`[sys.executable, 'gdal_calc.py', '-A',...]`The code you posted as an answer is also missing the `-` before `A` in `calc_cmd_*`, which might cause a problem once you get `gdal_calc.py` running. As a stackoverflow rule, would you mind removing your answer with the full code and putting that code in an edit to the original question?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've made the necessary changes and also made and additional update. Now I am receiving an entirely new error. 


[`"C:\Users\jack.UTILIS\Desktop\Components\Sigma_Test\ridofZsv2.py", line 23, in <module>
    subprocess.call([sys.executable,'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py', inHVFile, outVFile, '--calc=A+1'], env=gdal_env)
NameError: name 'gdal_env' is not defined`]




I appreciate all of your help, it's very kind.

Comment: @KosherMoses I can't imagine why `gdal_env` is not defined if you are running the code in the original question. Make sure that you specify the input raster file with `-A` and the output file with `--outfile=`. Also be sure to escape the backslashes by doing double backslashes: `'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py'`

Comment: I've made the changes you've suggested and now I'm receiving the following error.


[`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 335, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 332, in main
    doit(opts, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 157, in doit
    myOutType=gdal.GetDataTypeName(max(myDataTypeNum))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`]

Comment: @KosherMoses I don't know why this error is arising. Make sure that `-A` and `inVHFile` are separate items in the command list. Probably just a small syntax error like that... Do some double checking. If you are really confident it all is correct then try to specify the output type using `[..., `--type=Float32`, ...]` or whatever the type is....

Comment: @KosherMoses You are welcome. Happy it is finally working. You can go ahead and accept this answer as correct to close out the question.